# How to Open KML file (from assets folder)

Tags: google-maps, android-intent, kml

I have a KML file in assets folder. i want to open it into google earth or google map. but none of these worked.
This is what I tried:

For Google Map

```
private GoogleMap map;
KmlLayer layer;
Context context;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_locations);


    try {
        layer = new KmlLayer(map,getAssets().open("locations.kml"),context);
        layer.addLayerToMap();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

for Google earth

```
    File KML = null;
    try {
        KML = new File(String.valueOf(getAssets().open("locations.kml")));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Intent i = 
getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.earth");
    i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(KML), "xml");
    startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a new project with  Google Map Activity.
2. Now in the **onMapReady()** method use **retrieveFileFromResource()**

   ```
   private void retrieveFileFromResource() {
           try {
               KmlLayer kmlLayer = new KmlLayer(mMap, R.raw.kml, getApplicationContext());
               kmlLayer.addLayerToMap();
           } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
   ```

   3.Full code

   ```
   public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

   private GoogleMap mMap;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
       // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
       SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
               .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
       mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


   }

   @Override
   public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
       mMap = googleMap;

       retrieveFileFromResource();
   }

   private void retrieveFileFromResource() {
       try {
           KmlLayer kmlLayer = new KmlLayer(mMap, R.raw.kml, getApplicationContext());
           kmlLayer.addLayerToMap();
       } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
   }
   ```